# Converting polygon vectors into raster which is percent of pixel which is covered by polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, rasterization

I have maps of fish farms which I think might be relevant for my species distribution mode. However these maps are essentially just polygons drawn over individual fish cages. I’ve also got data on aquatic vegetation, depth, etc. which are in raster format. I want to make a new raster from the fish farm polygons, with the same extent and pixel size as the ones for the depth etc., but which includes, as a value in each pixel, the percent of the area which is covered by the polygons. So that if 15% of the area of the pixel was a polygon, the pixel would have a value of .15, if no fish farms were in that pixel, it would have a value of 0, etc.

How would I go about doing this using ArcGIS Pro?

So far I’ve tried to rasterise the polygons, but that ends up with having rasters where the polygons were with rather odd values on them whose provenance is unknown to me. I have also made a fishnet with grids the size of the desired raster but don’t know how to calculate the area of the intersect between fish farms and the grids.

I have also tried to use the tabulate intersection function, but once when I tried it I got an obviously wrong result of every grid having a percentage of the area with cages in them (which I can tell from the map isn’t the case) and once I got a “Parameter is Missing or Invalid” message

Comment: You need to add some images to your question to show the type of overlaps that exist in your data.

Comment: You're on the right track with the fishnet, make sure it aligns perfectly with your existing raster, then use calculate geometry https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm to get the sizes of your polygons after intersection, the area of the cell is height X width so divide the geometry areas by that and that's your percentage, calculate a new field of double or float with that value, now rasterize your intersected polygons and you will have the percentage as a raster.